# not showing the context menu after handling right click event

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, mouseevent, mousedown

I want to handle right click event on a particular div element. After digging through a number of answers in stackoverflow, I came up with this:

```
 $('#mydiv').mousedown(function(event) {
if ((event.which == 3)&& (event.target.nodeName == 'SPAN')){
     $("#outpdiv").append($(event.target).text().concat(" , "));
     event.preventDefault();
}
 });
```

As you can see, I am trying to to append the content of span elements inside mydiv to another div element outpdiv. This works fine, but the problem is after right click, the contextmenu is shown. Apparently, `event.preventDefault()` does not work. How can I get around this problem so that the context menu is not shown after you do the right click?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try capturing the `contextmenu` event and calling `preventDefault()` in that handler:

http://jsfiddle.net/cTp9x/

```
$('#mydiv').mousedown(function (event) {
    if ((event.which == 3) && (event.target.nodeName == 'SPAN')) {
        $("#outpdiv").append($(event.target).text().concat(" , "));        
    }
});

$(document).on('contextmenu', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
});
```

In response to your comment. If you only want to disable the context menu when you click that particular div, you can bind the handler to it. Switching between jQuery and native event handlers is messy, IMO:

```
$('#mydiv').on('contextmenu', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
});
```

Comment: I accepted your answer because you were the first one, but instead of disabling context menu the way you did, I added `document.getElementById('mydiv').oncontextmenu=new Function ("return false")`

Comment: yes I tried that. Apparently, the `e.preventDefault()` is not working for me. I am using http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6/jquery.min.js